# Angular 2 Routing ( cannot load component)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-routing

For some reason angular 2 is looking for my component in app/app/aboutus.component and I cannot seem to find where the problem is arising.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

aboutus.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angularS/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'about-us',
    templateUrl: 'app/aboutus.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AboutUsComponent {
    teammembers: String[];
    constructor() {

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.teammembers = ['raja', 'steve', 'trevor'];
    }

}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutUsComponent } from 'aboutus.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent}
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

main.ts

```
//main entry point into app
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Angular 2 Routing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a>Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['AboutUs']">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The Template I want to route to is aboutus.html which only has a `<h1>` tag.
I am just getting started with Angular 2 routing and have been having issues with getting angular to find my components. As of now, I am getting a XHR 404 error on the aboutus.component.js and I have ran an npm install.

Comment: Are app.routes.ts and aboutus.component.ts in the same folder?

Comment: yes all this files reside under the  app folder

Comment: try to write import { AboutUsComponent } from './aboutus.component'; note./ before filename

Comment: okay The file path has been updated correctly however it still sends a 404 error I can upload a screen snippet of my console

Comment: you have got path problem only else everything is okay.

Comment: also correct this > `import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angularS/router'`; to `@angular/router`

Comment: the path for the aboutUs component seem to be recognize from @Rems fix however there is a problem with angular locating the router module http://localhost/webDev/An2_routes/@angularS/router 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thank you for the Typo catch

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: yes! Angular 2 is now loading and finding my components successfully. I will have to continue to troubleshoot as the page is displaying with

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: '' platform-browser.umd.js:2320 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Comment: Grt good to know this.

Comment: Earlier threads mentioned that umd  for routing in angular 2 was not yet supported  may this be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other error try this,

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', component: AboutUsComponent}
 {path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent}
];
```

Comment: Thank You, I did not realize you needed to set an empty default path

Comment: Its a default path. When `AppComponent` gets initialized, it look for a default component for `<router-outlet>` which was not defined in your case. you can change it to any other default component eg.HomeComponent once you create it.